# Jhipster- allow non admin users to create users

Tags: spring-boot, authorization, jhipster

I have a user with role manager in jhipster, and this role should have the authority to create users.

I have implemented all front end functionality to allow this user to create users in user management. In admin.route.ts I provided the ROLE_MANAGER authority and in the canActivate method in user-management.component I gave the authority ROLE_MANAGER. I have also given permission .HasAnyAUthoirty() for both admin and manager roles in the /management/** APIs from the SecurityConfiguration class.

However, when I try open the user-management page,even though it opens, I see a message on top which says you are not authorized to see this page. THen when I create the user, I get the error

> Enter: io.xiges.asbestos.adm.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-03-11T21:40:58.263Z, principal=user, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
>   2019-03-12 08:40:58.267 DEBUG 25632 --- [ XNIO-2 task-24] i.x.a.adm.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Exit: io.xiges.asbestos.adm.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
>   2019-03-12 08:40:58.269  WARN 25632 --- [ XNIO-2 task-24] o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      : Forbidden: Access is denied
>   2019-03-12 08:40:58.272  WARN 25632 --- [ XNIO-2 task-24] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied.

In my application, I want to give all users in the role manager, the authority to create users. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you changed the `@PreAuthorize` annotations in `UserResource` ?

Comment: Thanks @GaëlMarziou. That's exactly what I was missing. I had to use @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')") to allow multiple roles. thanks!